# How to view the VF page with in the another VF page

Tags: visualforce

I have created tow VF page and i would like to show the one VF page with in the another VF page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using an iFrame or using the `<apex:include>` tag.  I would look into the include tag.

> apex:include A component that inserts a second Visualforce page into
>   the current page. The entire page subtree is injected into the
>   Visualforce DOM at the point of reference and the scope of the
>   included page is maintained.
>
> If content should be stripped from the included page, use the
>    component instead.
>
> Example
>
> ```
> <!-- Page: -->
>
> <apex:page id="thePage">
>   <apex:outputText value="(page) This is the page."/><br/>
>   <apex:include pageName="include"/>
> </apex:page>
>
> <!-- Page: include -->
> <apex:page id="theIncludedPage">
>   <apex:outputText value="(include) This is text from another page."/>
> </apex:page>
> ```

Se documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_include.htm)

Comment: @ sfdc_ninja please answer for the hsfdc_ninjattp://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45738/how-to-calculate-the-office-hours-except-holidays-hours-in-salesforce

Comment: how to include the managed package vf page?